# How can I make combobox heading more apparent?

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

In my previous question , [How do you add labels to the options in combobox and list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873045/how-do-you-add-labels-to-the-options-in-combobox)

I had asked about how I can add header to my combobox! The answer was perfect but I cant differentiate my headers and my options.
Is it possible to perhaps indented anything that can be selected?  Or make my headers bold? My code is pretty much the best answer of my previous question. Which is...

All the headings are not selectable.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxWithSections extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ComboBox<ComboBoxItem> combo = new ComboBox<>();
    combo.getItems().addAll(
        new ComboBoxItem("Short Duration", false),
        new ComboBoxItem("Last Hour",      true),
        new ComboBoxItem("Last 2 hours",   true),
        new ComboBoxItem("Last 24 hours",  true),
        new ComboBoxItem("",               false),
        new ComboBoxItem("Long Duration",  false),
        new ComboBoxItem("Last Month",     true),
        new ComboBoxItem("Last Year",      true)            
    );

    combo.setCellFactory(listView -> new ListCell<ComboBoxItem>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(ComboBoxItem item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setDisable(false);
            } else {
                setText(item.toString());
                setDisable(! item.isSelectable());
            }
        }
    });

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(null, combo, null, null, null);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 250, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static class ComboBoxItem {
    private final String name ;
    private final boolean selectable ;

    public ComboBoxItem(String name, boolean selectable) {
        this.name = name ;
        this.selectable = selectable ;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name ;
    }

    public boolean isSelectable() {
        return selectable ;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name ;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the cell factory.  The method updateItem is where the cell gets drawn.

```
        super.updateItem(item, empty);//does important things in super
        if (empty) {                  //what to do if cell is empty   
            setText(null);
            setDisable(false);        //reset the disabled state 
        } else {
            setText(item.toString()); //calls toString in your custom class
            setDisable(! item.isSelectable()); //what stops you from selecting
            setTextFill(item.isSelectable()
                    ?Color.BLUE:Color.BLACK); //changing the color
        }
```

You could add color or font to your custom class and just use that instead of isSelectable() to determine the color.

You could also use CSS to style disabled cells differently but that may be less flexible.

Comment: Similarly to the idea of styling disabled cells differently with css, I experimented with using a css pseudoclass when I was testing the solution to the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873045/how-do-you-add-labels-to-the-options-in-combobox) and it worked very nicely.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for all the pseudoClass gists BTW, that's where I learned them.  In this case I think he could just use `.combo-box-popup .list-cell:disabled` since that is already set.

Comment: Yes, certainly in this case just using `:disable` would work. However there could be use cases in which you wanted to disable one of the "selectable" items for other reasons, in which case a distinct pseudoclass might be useful.