# How to make combobox with multiple dropdowns?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want to do make combobox ala dropdown menu like it's on many websites.

- Category A

  - aa
  - ab
  - ac
- Category B

  - ba
  - bb
  - bc

Something like:

[image: https://ugate.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/scroll-menu3.png?w=630]

I didn't found anywhere a similar problem. And I don't know where to start. Should I do a custom combobox using contextmenu instead of a listview, as contextmenu is would do a pretty similar job

Comment: Just to clarify: You're looking for a way to create a menu that only expands the list of options in a subcategory, as you hover/select the group item, not for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873045/how-do-you-add-labels-to-the-options-in-combobox-and-list ?

Comment: That image you linked looks more like a [`javafx.scene.control.MenuButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html) than a `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, for that purpose I would use a Button - Context Menu - Menu - CheckMenuItem approach.

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
Menu menu1 = new Menu("Scrollable Submenu");
Menu menu2 = new Menu("Regular Submenu");
contextMenu.getItems().addAll(menu1, menu2);

for (int i = 1 ; i <= 25; i++) {
    CheckMenuItem checkMenuItem = new CheckMenuItem("Option " + i);
    menu1.getItems().add(checkMenuItem);
}

Button button = new Button();
button.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
root.setTop(new HBox(button));

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

primaryStage.setTitle("Dropdown Menu");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();

button.setOnAction(e -> button.getContextMenu().show(button.getScene().getWindow()));
```

Let me know if this approach fits your needs.